# How do you recode a variable?

Tags: r, variables, recode

I have a variable (animal) that sits in a data frame (data). It is coded 1 = dog, 2 = cat, 3 = bunny, 4 = horse, 5 = monkey.

I want to recode it so that horse and bunny = 2 and everything else = 1. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you share an example of data. It's not clear how it is that your data is coded, if it is factor or not.

Comment: @RicVillalba sorry I cant!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way. Untested, since there are no data.

- The logical condition `data$animal %in% 3:4` returns `FALSE/TRUE`, coded as `0/1`;
- add `1L` to get `1/2`

That's it.

```
data$animal <- 1L + (data$animal %in% 3:4)
```

Comment: thank you! that works! Do you know how I could code it instead to 1 for bunny and horse and 0 for everything else?

Comment: @RosieJones Remove the `1L`. If you want 0/1 and not 1/2, don't add 1.

Comment: that seems to just give me FALSE for every value?

Comment: @RosieJones No, not if you *keep the plus sign*. Alternatively, and more readable, remove the plus sign and write `as.integer(data$animal %in% 3:4)`.